# Taylor series of $1+2x^2+3x^4+\sin(e^{2x}+1)\log(1+x^4)x^4$?

Tags: taylor-expansion

Taylor series of $1+2x^2+3x^4+\sin(e^{2x}+1)\log(1+x^4)x^4$?

I'm wondering whether this can be gained by considering the individual terms or by differentiating the whole?

The differentiation of this seems to lead to quite a mess, so I'm guessing a term-wise solution.

Comment: Don't differentiate the whole thing, use the expansions of log, sin, exp and sub them in and you can get the first few terms by multiplying out.

Comment: Yeah, the question is actually asking for the series up to only some n terms.

Comment: How many terms?  The messy piece only contributes to $x^8$ and higher order.

Comment: It asks for n=4.